# ToggleClass with multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery's hide and toggleclass functions to switch between page elements.  It half works, but when going from one to another, it switches the mainpagecontent class on.

For example, if you click "Buy Now", it correctly removes the mainpagecontent class items and displays the buynow class items.

But if you then click another page, say, "Questions", it then displays the mainpagecontent class items (which I don't want) and then the questions class items below.

I only want the mainpagecontent class items to show when no other page is showing.

This is my jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jamesthemonkeh/to7tLLde/.

This is the jquery section in question :

```
$("#contactpage").click(function() {
    $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    $('.whoareyoupage').hide("slow");
    $('.buynow').hide("slow");
    $('.questionspage').hide("slow");
    $('.contactpage').slideToggle("slow");
});
    $("#contactpage2").click(function() {
    $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    $('.whoareyoupage').hide("slow");
    $('.buynow').hide("slow");
    $('.questionspage').hide("slow");
    $('.contactpage').slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#whoareyoupage").click(function() {
    $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    $('.contactpage').hide("slow");
    $('.buynow').hide("slow");
    $('.questionspage').hide("slow");
    $('.whoareyoupage').slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#buynow").click(function() {
    $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    $('.contactpage').hide("slow");
    $('.whoareyoupage').hide("slow");
    $('.questionspage').hide("slow");
    $('.bigbutton').hide("slow");
    $('.buynow').slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#buynow2").click(function() {
    $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    $('.contactpage').hide("slow");
    $('.whoareyoupage').hide("slow");
    $('.questionspage').hide("slow");
    $('.bigbutton').hide("slow");
    $('.buynow').slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#questionspage").click(function() {
    $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    $('.contactpage').hide("slow");
    $('.whoareyoupage').hide("slow");
    $('.buynow').hide("slow");
    $('.questionspage').slideToggle("slow");
});

function contactForm(){
  var isOpen = false;

  function toggleContactForm() {
    if (isOpen) {
      $('.mainpagecontent').fadeIn("50000");
    } else {
      $('.mainpagecontent').fadeOut("50000");
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
  }

    $('#contactpage').on('click', toggleContactForm);
    $('#whoareyoupage').on('click', toggleContactForm);
    $('#buynow').on('click', toggleContactForm);
    $('#questionspage').on('click', toggleContactForm);
}

contactForm();
```

Can anyone kindly advise?

Thanks
James

Comment: I cannot see any usage of the `toggleclass` command here...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/to7tLLde/1/ check this fiddle. you just need to remove extra function that you created.